# Openjpa maven plugin error: Failed to execute goal : enhance

Tags: java, migration, java-11, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

I am working on a migration activity **(JDK 1.8 to JDK 11)**.

- My **pom.xml** having

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>**/entities/*.class</includes>
                    <excludes>**/entities/XML*.class</excludes>
                    <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                    <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhancer</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                        <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

It was working fine with JDK 1.8, when I changed the JDK version to 11 I am facing this issue while running **mvn install**.

below is the error I am getting.

[image: error].

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Instead of changing to java-11, change to Java-17. It is the latest version of java and has LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, just changed the version **org.apache.openjpa** from 2.4.0 to 3.2.0. ( in logs there were error which was indicating towards 3.2.0 version).

may be compatibility issue with JDK11 but it solved the problem.